# Se puede crear un AccountManager en IOS y Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

En android se deja crear cuentas de aplicaciones en el telefono para guardar datos de sesion cuando se autentica o se loguea un usuario en nuestra app ejemplo: AccountManager.

¿Se puede hacer esto mismo en iOS? ¿O existe algo similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que con los `Keychain Services` del framework `Security` podrías implementar algo parecido al `AccountManager` de Android. Si eres usuario de Mac OSX, es un concepto muy similar al `Keychain` de escritorio: guardar cuentas y contraseñas securizadas con una contraseña maestra. En el caso del móvil (si tiene la capacidad) puedes hacer incluso que estas contraseñas sean protegidas por huella dactilar.

Aquí puedes encontrar la documentación oficial de Apple sobre esto: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts

Así mismo, Ray Wenderlich tiene un tutorial bastante bien explicado con ejemplos en Swift. Es este enlace: https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password

Espero haberte ayudado. ¡Un saludo!